# How can we let recurring job only trigger on one instance in case of scale out

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ftp, hangfire, hangfire-autofac

I use Hangfire to read files from FTP server and I have multiple server instances to read from FTP. I need the recurring job only trigger on one instance to prevent the same job to read from same file.

```
var jobId = BackgroundJob.Enqueue<FtpImageJob>(j => j.ExecuteAsync(null, device.NumericId, device.DeviceId, device.VehicleId, device.TenantId));
                BackgroundJob.ContinueJobWith<FtpDeleteJob>(jobId, j => j.ExecuteAsync(null, numericId), JobContinuationOptions.OnAnyFinishedState);
```

Comment: I corrected a misspelling in your title, this was probably the reason you didn't get answers. Be careful when spelliing your title next time... regards

Answer (score 0):

You may either use paid Hangfire.Pro package with Mutex feature or decorate your job function with `[DisableConcurrentExecution]` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to restrict execution of job to only one of the many Hangfire servers, use a separate queue that only exists on one server. This way your recurring job will only execute on that hangfire server that's serving that queue.